# upgrade my application from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2

Tags: ssl, https, http2

Currently my application is using http/1.1 protocol to send and receive the response on Tomcat server.

To support multiplexing i am going to use the HTTP/2 protocol to improve performance.

My web server is tomcat, i have deployed my app on it.

so i need to switch to HTTP/2?

Tomcat 9.2

I want to move from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 protocol for all my request in application

Comment: Please mention which version of tomcat and how you are deploying your code ?

Comment: Tomcat 9.2 and we will keep all our war files in webapps folders